# Email sending form, checkboxes selection, checkboxes limitation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello everyone, I'm having difficulty trying to figure out what's wrong.
So ive got a email sending form with checkboxes and checkboxes limitation, however, it doesn't work properly.
This is checkbox limitation script.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function chkcontrol(j) {
    var total=0;
    for(var i=0; i < document.form1.ckb.length; i++){
    if(document.form1.ckb[i].checked){
total =total +1;}
if(total > 3){
alert("Please Select only three") 
document.form1.ckb[j].checked = false ;
return false;
}
}
} </script>
```

This is the form

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="send_form_email2.php">


<tr bgcolor=''#ffffcc''><td > </td><td ><b>I&#353;sirinkite viena ar daugiau produktus.          
</b></td></tr><br>
<tr bgcolor=''#f1f1f1'' ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=multi mama balzamas 
onclick='chkcontrol(0)';></td><td >Multi-Mama Balzamas</td></tr><br>
<tr bgcolor=''#ffffff'' ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=multi mama kompresai
onclick='chkcontrol(1)';></td><td >Multi-Mama kompresai</td></tr><br>
<tr bgcolor=''#f1f1f1'' ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=multi gyn actigel
onclick='chkcontrol(2)';></td><td >Multi-Gyn ActiGel</td></tr><br>
<tr bgcolor=''#ffffff'' ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=multi gyn liquigel
onclick='chkcontrol(3)';></td><td >Multi-Gyn LiquiGel</td></tr><br>
<tr bgcolor=''#f1f1f1'' ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=multi oral gel
onclick='chkcontrol(4)';></td><td >Multi-Oral Gel</td></tr><br>
<tr bgcolor=''#ffffff'' ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=Multi-Oral Remi Dent
onclick='chkcontrol(5)';></td><td >Multi-Oral Remi Dent</td></tr><br>
<tr bgcolor=''#f1f1f1'' ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=Maxiderma Rankom 
onclick='chkcontrol(6)';></td><td >Maxiderma Rankom</td></tr><br>
<tr bgcolor=''#ffffff'' ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=Maxiderma Kojom 
onclick='chkcontrol(7)';></td><td >Maxiderma Kojom</td></tr><br>
<tr bgcolor=''#ffffff'' ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=Physiosalt   
onclick='chkcontrol(8)';></td><td >Physiosalt</td></tr><br>
<tr bgcolor=''#ffffff'' ><td ><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=AquaBloc
onclick='chkcontrol(9)';></td><td >AquaBloc</td></tr><br>

<p><table width="561">
<tr>
<td width="212" align="right" valign="top">
<label for="name">*Vardas</label>
</td>
<td width="337" valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="150" size="50">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="right">
<label for="company">*Pavard&#279;</label>
</td>
<td width="337" valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="150" size="50">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="right">
<label for="telephone">*Miestas</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="150" size="50">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="right">
<label for="email">*El.pa&#353;tas</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="180" size="50">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="right">
<label for="ckb"><br />
</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="212" align="right" valign="top">
<label for="name">*Gatv&#279;, namo Nr., buto Nr:</label>
</td>
<td width="337" valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="150" size="50">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="212" align="right" valign="top">
<label for="name">*Pa&#353;to kodas</label>
</td>
<td width="337" valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="150" size="50">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="right">
<label for="comments">*Komentaras</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
<center><input type="submit" VALUE="  Siusti  " id="submit_button" disabled></center>
<input type="checkbox" id="TOS" value="1" onClick="agreeTerms(this)"> Sutinku su
taisyklemis. <a target="_blank" href="siuntimo.html" rel="nofollow" >Taisykles</a><br> 
</p> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and this is the php email form

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
$cbk = array();

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "info@samplebox.eu";
$email_subject = "Contact form";
$email_from = "";

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Vardas: ".clean_string($_POST["name"])."\n";
$email_message .= "El. Pastas: ".clean_string($_POST["email"])."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($_POST["telephone"])."\n";
$email_message .= "Produktai: ".implode(" ", $_POST['ckb'])."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($_POST["comments"])."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->
<center>
<img src="images/logo.png" />
<br>
<br>
Greitai susisieksime<br>
<br>
<a href="index.html">Namai</a></center>
<?php
}
?>
```

Whenver those checkboxes are selected, and when you click submit button, I will get an email with all the information EXCEPT it doesn't show which checkboxes were selected.

Can anyone help me with this? :)
Edit: This is the following code that inside

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myForm = document.forms.form1;
var allInputs= myForm.elements['ckb[]'];


var len = allInputs.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)

function chkcontrol(j) {
var total=0;
for(var i=0; i < document.form1.ckb.length; i++){
if(document.form1.ckb[i].checked){
total =total +1;}
if(total > 3){
alert("Please Select only three") 
document.form1.ckb[j].checked = false ;
return false;
}
}
}
} </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a google search I found someone trying to do a similar thing. I think you need to change

```
name=ckb
```

to

```
name=ckb[]
```

So php will know that "ckb" is indeed an array of checkboxes.
Hopefully this helps

to your comment try this:

```
var allInputs = document.form1.elements['ckb[]'];


var len = allInputs.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
   your code here
}
```

We chatted a lot and it turned out the html itself had a few problems and didn't call the functions but the code above is working after all.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! It does work, but checkbox limiter breaks, you can check as many checkboxs as you want. :/ And I need it to be able to check only 5 max check boxes

Comment: Uhm, sorry, but do I add this in <script> checkbox limiter</script> code? Or somewhere else? I added it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmmm... It worked for a lot of people and yes, you add it in your javascript functions. did you change the "id_of_form" to "form1"?

Comment: Yeah, this is how it looks like. I edited the first page, its at the very end, the full code

Comment: I'm really desperate right now :c Tried everything, but it doesn't seems to work :c

Comment: Don't be desperate. We'll get this working. OK so first of all remove the var myForm and var allInputs lines and replace them with
var allInputs = document.form1.elements['ckb[]']; I'm also adding it to my answer

Comment: I removed those 2 lines of codes and replaced them with the one you provided. You can check all checkboxes without getting an alert pop up window telling you that you can only check 3 boxes in this case. I think it has something to do with the "[]" thing. Since adding cbk to name="cbk" you get the alert, but you don't get any selected check boxes when you send the email, and if you do name"cbk[]" the alert doesn't shows up so you can check as many boxes as you want, but you get the checked boxes when you send the email

Comment: Ok, right after you create the allInputs variable add this line then tell me what it outputs: alert(allInputs);

Comment: I think I just found the problem - you are doing this->(var i=0; i < document.form1.ckb.length; i++) 
 instead of what I wrote to you in the for command, try what I wrote for you in my answer

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know I might be doing it wrong, but I added the line right after the var allInputs= myForm.elements['ckb[]']; I get the email with the products selected, but it still doesn't give me the alert and people can check as many boxes as they want. Is there anyway you could help me outside of stackoverflow? Via skype or teamviewer or any kind of software. I really have a feeling that I'm doing something wrong, I need someone who is experianced who can look at the codes :)

Comment: when we fix this I will post what was wrong on here